# NoMethodError: undefined method `meow?' for # - ruby mixin failing?

Tags: ruby, module, mixins

I'm playing with some of the very basics of ruby mixins, and for some reason can't access behavior from my module.

Running this on Ruby Fiddle:

```
module Cats
  MEOW = "meow meow meow"

  def Cats.meow?
    return Cats::MEOW
  end
end

class Example
  include Cats

  def sample
    return "it's a sample"
  end
end

e = Example.new
puts e.sample
puts e.meow?
```

This keeps returning `NoMethodError: undefined method 'meow?' for #`

My understanding of how mixins should work from [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_modules.htm) makes me feel like I should be able to validly call `e.meow?`, and get back the same result I would get from calling `Cats.meow?`.

Here's the code in [RubyFiddle](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/1dac7/2).

Incredibly basic, but any ideas where I'm falling down here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, I was being overly specific when defining `Cats.meow?`. If you want to use a module as a mixin you'll want to define your methods more generally, not with respect to their specific module namespace.

So instead of

```
def Cats.meow?
  ...
end
```

it should have been

```
def meow?
  ...
end
```

This lets you call `e.meow?`, since the method definition no longer limits it just to the `Cats` namespace.

Whoops.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule to using `include` and `extend` in Ruby:

If you want to use your module as a namespace

```
module Outer
  module Inner
    def self.my_method
      "namespaced method!"
    end
  end
end
```

You use it like this `Outer::Inner::my_method` or `Outer::Inner.my_method`.

And if you want to use the module as a mixin:

```
# In some cases it makes sense to use names ending in -able, since it expreses
# what kind of messages you can send to an instance or class that mixes
# this module in.
# Like Devise's Recoverable module: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/f39c6fd92774cb66f96f546d8d5e8281542b4e78/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb#L24

module Fooable
  def foo
    "#{self} has been foo'ed!"
  end
end
```

Then you can `include` it (instances of Something obtain #foo):

```
class Something
  include Fooable # Now Something.new can receive the #foo message.
end

Something.new.foo
=> "#<Something:0x0055c2dc104650> has been foo'ed!"
```

Or you can extend it (Something itself obtains #foo as a class message):

```
class Something
  extend Fooable # Now Something can receive the #foo message.
end

Something.foo
=> "Something has been foo'ed!"
```